# Convert recursion to iteration in service calls in Angular

Tags: angular, recursion, iteration

I have this kind of HTTP request function in an Angular service:

```
doRequest() {
  return this.http.get<any>("/DoStuffController/DoStuff");
}
```

It's called from an Angular component. The thing is, depending on the return value, the component might need to keep calling it. The return value tells Angular if it should keep calling it or stop. Something like this:

```
doRequest() {
  this.service.doRequest().subscribe(data => {
    if (data.continue) {
      doRequest();
    }
  );
}
```

There might be hundreds of calls in succession. I fear this might cause a literal stack overflow (pun intended). I'd like to convert this recursion into iteration as something like this (probably won't work):

```
doRequest() {
  var continue: boolean = true;
  do {
    this.service.doRequest().subscribe(data =>
      continue = data.continue;
    );
  } while (continue);
}
```

Is this kind of thing possible?

Comment: I think javascript since ES2015 enabled Tail Call Optimization so you may not need to worry about using recursion instead of iteration, I stand corrected

Answer (score 0):

That is possible but why you are requesting something until the API response continue false, I think you should have to change the logic from your API not doing this in the frontend

Comment: This is because Angular has to react to every call in turn, in order to display to the user how the logic is progressing.